# Reference a script/model from within the same Toolbox

Tags: arcpy, arctoolbox

in a script within a toolbox I'm trying to call a model in that same toolbox. Currently I have to hardwire the path.

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"[PATH]", "LLPGToolbox")
arcpy.llpg_LLPGToolbox(inputFolder, output15, output21, output24, processedLLPG)
```

Is there a way of doing this without the need to hardwire paths each time (i.e. 'look in the toolbox I'm in for script X').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I currently do it:

```
import arcpy

tbx_path = r'C:\ArcGIS\Toolbox.tbx'
tbx_alias = 'MyCustomToolbox'
tbx = arcpy.ImportToolbox(tbx_path,tbx_alias)
tbx
>>> <module 'MyCustomToolbox' (built-in)>
```

Then I run

```
custom_model = getattr(arcpy,'{0}_{1}'.format('Model',tbx_alias))
```

which is essentially building a string that I can put after `arcpy.`:

```
'arcpy.Model_MyCustomToolbox'
```

Now I can use `custom_model()` as a regular Python function (with input args etc).

Answer (score 6):

ArcGIS has to be able to find the Toolbox, but that doesn't mean you have to specify the path each time.

The easiest way may be to just ensure that the toolboxes are in the same folder, and then just use the file name, for example:

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox('Toolbox.tbx,'toolboxalias')
```

If you are running the PythonToolbox tool from within ArcGIS, the directory that contains that toolbox is added to the path (look at the value of `sys.path`).
When you use `arcpy.ImportToolbox` without a full path, ArcGIS will check all of the directories listed in `sys.path` and then it also checks `arcpy.env.workspace`.

If locating the toolboxes in the same folder isn't possible, you can modify the paths that ArcGIS checks. You can add the folder to `sys.path` in Python directly in individual scripts or more permanently by modifying the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable.

You can also set `arcpy.env.workspace` to the appropriate folder that contains the toolbox, but I'm not sure why that would be more beneficial that just supplying the full path.